# sbt change settings of project in dependsOn

Tags: scala, sbt

Ok, so I have the following project structure:

```scala
val projectA = project.
// assume rest of config

val projectB = project // assume rest of config
.dependsOn(A)
```

Now for reasons when running, for example, tests of projectB instead of compiling projectA classes in its own dir (`projectA/target/scala...`) add them to projectB target, to have `projectB/target/projectA/target/...`.

I've tried the following config in `build.sbt` and calling `sbt 'projectB' ...` without success:

```scala
val projectB = project // assume rest of config
.dependsOn(A)
.settings(projectA / target := file("new target dir"))
```

but if the same config is set directly in `sbt` command, like:

```sh
sbt 'project B' 'set projectA / target := file("new target dir")' ...
```

It works fine and I see the new dir created inside `projectB/target/projectA` with everything generated.

Can't figure out what I'm missing here for config in `build.sbt` not to work, appreciate any help.

Comment: May I ask why you care about where the files are generated?

Comment: Sure, I know it's not usual due to standards but in the real scenario there are more projects and dependencies between them. The thing is that I'm using sbt-coverage when running the tests and they run in parallel, the coverage option makes project and it's dependencies to be recompiled and being parallel conflicts because one invalidates the classes of the other. So my idea was to, only at test phase, do the above

Comment: Sounds like even if there is such a solution it is a bad practice. Why not just running `sbt compile` and then `sbt test`?